# Please help me to remove the bug from android studio

Tags: android-studio-3.0

When I start the android studio, it is throwing an exception message happened due to flutter and updation on android studio.Please help me to fix the bug[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsnHx.png)
Please click on the this link to check the screenshot of the bug I encountered and please help me with the issue.
[Link please click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVkRG.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.